How to set up properly a cookie in Acquia Drupal 10
I checked the documentation on the Acquia Doc Page: https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud-platform/performance/varnish/cookies. So I can use the cookie as my condition in the htaccess.
But I'm unable to get the cookie value.
Can anyone help me figure out how to properly set up cookies in Acquia Drupal?
